# Codeigniter upgrade 2.0.2 to 3.1.10 session problem on local mamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I'm updating my Codeigniter. I've deleted de system folder and replaced it with the new one. I've followed the [Upgrading from 2.2.x to 3.0.x instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html). These are my new settings for the session:

```
$config['sess_driver']      = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_save_path']   = APPPATH.'/sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_domain']   = '';
$config['cookie_path']     = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'    = FALSE;
```

I use:

```
  $newdata = array(
          'username'  => $member->email,
          'email'     => $member->member_id,
          'logged_in' => TRUE
  );

  $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

I can print user, email after the set_userdata, but when I redirect to the default page in my admin, I get

> $_SESSION empty

(except for the __ci_last_regenerate )

The folder is "OK"(I can see the new session).

I'm using MAMP PRO 5.3 with on port 8890 for ssl. 
I've tried database driver with same results.

Comment: I've tried PHP 7.1.26, 7.0.33, 5.6

Comment: Try using `$this->session->set_userdata('index',$newdata)` and then access it with `$this->session->userdata['index']` (since you're using CI sessions, it's best to use `$this->session` rather than `$_SESSION` (the `'index'` part is because CI tends to misbehave if you don't nest the session variables within an index... it can have any name you like)

Comment: In the above example, you'd use `$this->session->userdata['index']['username']` or you could loop through a whole index with `foreach ($this->session->userdata['index'] as $s)` and then just use `$s->username`, `$s->email`, etc

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, thanks but same results. I've added error_log to Session and I can see that session_start() is called a couple of times for 1 login()

Comment: you may be having a conflict there (using native PHP sessions in your code alongside CI sessions does cause a mess). I'd suggest removing al `session_start()` calls in your code and just autoload the CI session library.

Comment: The only session_start() is in Session lib but when I redirect, the autoload of Session is call again